# Gmail Android showing no email in primary folder

Tags: gmail

Since a few days ago, my Android Gmail shows no messages in the primary folder as you can see on the screenshot below.

> [image]

All the other tabs (social, updates) are running fine.

I have another Google account configured on this phone and all tabs are showing fine also. I confirm (just in case) that I actually have a lot of emails in this tab and I can access them correctly when using the desktop web app.

Also, I still have a notification when a new email arrives, I can click on the notification and see the email, but as soon as I close it, I can't access it anymore since the app always show that I have no emails in the primary tab.

Of course, I have tried to reboot my phone with no success.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try removing the Gmail update (uninstall). Then add the accounts.

Comment: I can't uninstall Gmail app from my phone. it's installed by default and can't be remove.

Comment: You can remove the updates that have been installed still you bought the phone. Remove the updates, then check if the problem persists.